# in dev c++ my library is missing how to install it

Tags: c, strlen

//my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
char txt[] = "xyz";
printf("%d", strlen(txt));
return 0;
}
```

//error is strlen  is not declared in this scope

//it should work my code is correct

Comment: You need the `<string.h>` header file

Comment: Why do you think your code is correct as is?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen says:

> Defined in header `<string.h>`

P.S. It also says that the return type is `size_t`, which is unsigned, and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf says that the printf specifier for `size_t` is `z`, so the format string should be `"%zu"`.

Answer (score 2):

### issues

- You're missing the <string.h> header for `strlen()`. More info  [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/?kw=string.h).
- The return type of strlen is that of size_t not int so use %zu for the format

#### fix:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  // The header you were missing
int main(void) {
    char txt[] = "xyz";
    printf("%zu", strlen(txt));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The format string should be `%zu`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf